# Expecting replica set member, but found a STANDALONE. Removing x.x.x.x:27017 from client view of cluster

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, monitoring

Not able to connect to mongo standalone node experiencing below error.

ERROR [cluster-ClusterId{value='asdfs', description='null'}-x.x.x.x:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Expecting replica set member, but found a STANDALONE. Removing x.x.x.x:27017 from client view of cluster.

Is it okay to give multiple Ip's in config file while only one mongo node is there?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it okay to give multiple Ip's in config file while only one mongo node is there?

Not for standalone connections, no.

Specify the address of your standalone only.